# zero-initialisation of storage values in constructor or gas optimization

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

is it better to pay extra gas to initialise storage variables that are empty as zeroes in the constructor, or save the gas since the default is zero?

Comment: Should I pay for something that I already have, or should I not pay for it because I already have it? Hmmmm, tough decision... You know what, I think I'll pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a variable to the default (0) in the constructor or directly in the contract won't make a difference for execution cost when changing that variable later on. Leaving the variables on the default variable will save you some gas on deployment.

For example, let's say we have the following contract:

```
contract Foo {
  uint256 public bar;
    
  function setBar (uint _bar) public {
    bar = _bar;
  }
}
```

Deploying this contract costs 106,769 gas (in Remix). Calling `setBar` with a value of `1` (setting `bar` to `1`) has a cost of 41,684 gas.

If we assign `bar` directly, e.g.

```
  uint256 public bar = 0;
```

deployment costs go up to 107,783 gas. Calling `setBar` has the same gas cost.

We can also assign `bar` in the constructor:

```
  constructor () {
    bar = 0;
  }
```

This results in a deployment cost of 107,995 gas, and `setBar` still has the same cost.

Comment: Hi I'm aware of this hence the question of what is best practice due to the nature of the EVM and fees

Comment: In static programming languages it's always best to to be as explicit as possible however since there is a cost of being so in solidity, my question remains, what to choose?